# PHP: Array Value to String

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

So I’m trying to convert each value, of an array, into a string.. But I can’t get it to work.
My best result is to get letters from the values.

I have a form where I post checkbox values into the database and later I want to echo the selected values:

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="Rock"> Rock</label>

<label class="form-check-inline">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="Funk"> Funk</label>

<label class="form-check-inline">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value=“Jazz”> Jazz</label>
</div>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['update_profile'])){
    $genre = implode(',', $_POST['genre']);
    $sql_update = "UPDATE user_profile SET genre = ‘$genre’ WHERE user_id = ‘$user_id’”;
…
}
```

In the database row the selected value look like this;
“Rock, Funk, Jazz”

Fine. Everything seems to work as it should.
But I can’t figure out how to separate the values..

```
        if($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_all_users)){
          if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
              $row_genre = array($row[1]);

        foreach ($row_genre as $key => $value) {
        echo $value[1];
        }

        }
    }
}
```

When I do a  print_r ($row_genre);
I get this result:

```
Array ( [0] => Rock,Funk,Jazz)
```

What kind of a array is that?

The result I echo in the foreach is R (The first letter in Rock - The first value )
I have tried to implode.. Dosen’t make a difference.
So how can I convert each value to a string?

Comment: You have an array with one element `[0]`, a comma separated list.

Comment: Switch `$row_genre = array($row[1]);` to `$row_genre = explode(',',$row[1]);`. And then only use `echo $value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like like `$row[1] = Rock,Funk,Jazz` so `$row[1]` itself is a string and comma-separated values.

If you want to convert the string to an array you can do it using `explode` function:

```
$row_genre = explode(',', $row[1]);
```

You can then go through that `$row_gen` array like this:

```
foreach($row_genre as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Explode is the answer!
When I do a print_r I get this result:
Array ( [0] => Rock [1] => Funk [2] => Jazz [3] )
Looks much better.
I had to make the foreach like this:
              foreach ($row_genre as $key => $value) {
                echo "$value";
                }

To get the result I wanted.

Comment: If you just want to use value then you can also use only $row_genre as $val

Answer (score 0):

You have an array that contains one element that is a string.  You can get the array value as its string by `$row_genre[0]`.  Or if you would prefer, you can perform an `explode(..)` on `$row_genre[0]` to split the comma separated values into their own array.

```
$genres = explode(',', $row_genre[0]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php